# Qt Creator "The program has unexpectedly finished."

Tags: windows, qt, project, qt-creator

Yesterday I installed Qt Creator and the Qt Library 5.0.1. When I created a new project and wanted to see how it looks, so I build and run the program and I got the following error:

```
Starting C:\Users\Khaled\workspace_qt\Test-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\Test.exe...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
C:\Users\Khaled\workspace_qt\Test-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MinGW_32bit-Debug\debug\Test.exe exited with code -1073741511
```

I got the same error when I tried to build and run the address book application from the example section.

I looked for other questions here, and I read one that said to check `g++` version and to change toolchain from the `Build & Run` section in the setting, but there is nothing that says toolchain. I also read one where it said to try to chnage between debug and release mode, both didn't work. I also just read a post about using Event Viewer to see the lacking dlls but I couldn't find anything.

Why am I getting this error message and how can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: run in debug mode, your program is probably crashing... to broad to answer

Comment: The above error message is when running my code in debug mode

Comment: sorry my mistake on the formulation :). run with the debugger.

Comment: In the debugger when I click the start debugging I get the following message `During startup program exited with code 0x0000139`

Comment: and in the application output tab I have `Debugging starts
Debugging has finished`

Comment: I dont know if this helps, but I have previously installed mingw on my own, and when I installed Qt is checked the mingw too, however they didn't add their mingw to the path so I didn't think it will matter, is this the case?

Comment: 1) use dependency walker to make sure no library is missing. 2) Check if your code doesn't crash. just search for `dependency walker` in SO or google.

Comment: I used `dependency walker` and I'm getting two yellow circles with a question mark in them, `QT5CORED.DLL` and `QT5WIDGETSD.DLL`

Comment: I looked in the Qt folder and found the 2 files above in `C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\bin`

Comment: Finally, it worked. I had to make a new kit in the `Build & Run` and point it to Qt's mingw and it finally worked

Answer (score 2):

If you run your application by clicking on it or using cmd (basically not through Qt), you will get a Windows system error informing you of the problem. If you're missing DLL's (which you seem to be), you'll be told which ones, although it will only tell you one at a time.